# Argument 'DemoController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the above angular error, and I am not sure what the problem is.

I am using a router to call a template and the related JS file.

Here is my router code:

...

```
$router.config([

            {
                path:'/preview',
                component: 'connections/preview'
            }
            ]);
```

...
My template file has the same name and used a controller as below:

...

```
<div ng-controller="PreviewController as prevCtrl">
```

...

And the JS file is as below.

...

```
(function (){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myMod',[]).controller('PreviewController', function($http){

var vm = this;

        $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/30e2a")
            .success(function(response) {
            //Dummy data taken from JSON file
            vm.firstName = response.firstName;
            vm.lastName = response.lastName;
            vm.dateAdded = response.dateAdded;
            vm.typeofDB = response.typeofDB;
            vm.accessLevel= response.accessLevel;
            vm.description = response.fileDescription;
            vm.fileSize = response.fileSize;
            vm.columns = response.columns;
            vm.rows = response.rows;
            vm.demoFileName = response.fileName;
            vm.demoFileType = response.fileType; 
            vm.usersName = response.usersName;


};
```

...

When I am loading the page, I am getting the following error:

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PreviewController' is not a function, got undefined

I guess my angular script is not getting loaded.

Can someone guide me as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably already defined your module elsewhere. In the code above, the square braces redefine it. So if you did define it elsewhere, just change:

```
angular.module('myMod',[]).controller('PreviewController', function($http){
```

To:

```
angular.module('myMod').controller('PreviewController', function($http){
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Your syntax all looks fine. It's going to be something silly like not loading the JavaScript file or something like that. If you can't find it a Codepen or Plunkr will probably be necessary.